# How to add a new record into a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to add a new entry to this into the "votes" section:

```
["blue",[true, false]]
```

```
{   "votes":[
     ["white",[true, true]],
     ["green",[true, false]]
   ],
   "config":{
      "title":"TEST",
      "options":[
         "first",
         "second"
      ]
   }
}
```

My code:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('./data/'.$_GET['id']);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// insert a new record
$data[] = array("votes" => "blue",true, true);

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('./data/'.$_GET['id'], $newJsonString);
```

The new record will only be appended to the JSon array. How do I get a new entry under the section "votes"?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Your problem happens entirely after the JSON has been properly decoded (and is thus no longer JSON), and entirely before you re-encode it (thus it's not JSON again yet).

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet doesn't work because you are trying to add new value into the root node. Also, you have a typo with your boolean values inside `votes` node

You should select the `votes` node like this:

```php
$jsonString = file_get_contents('./data/'.$_GET['id']);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// insert a new record into votes node
$data['votes'][] = ["blue", [true, true]];

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('./data/'.$_GET['id'], $newJsonString);
```